# Getting undefined when trying to retrieve value of the element on the page

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I am quite new to JavaScript and not able to get why below code is returning `undefined` when trying to do console log.

```
casper.getVersionOfDocs = function getVersionOfDocs() {
    casper.then(function(){
        var listItems = this.evaluate(function () {
            var nodes = document.querySelectorAll('#cp-search-facets > div > div.panel-pane.pane-search-facet-product-version > div > div > ul > li');
            return [].map.call(nodes, function(node) {
                return {
                    text: node.nodeValue
                };
            });
        });
        for(index = 0; index < listItems.length; index++){
            console.log(listItems[index]["value"]);
        };
    });
};
```

Output:

```
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
undefined
```

[image]

Comment: Try console log `console.log(listItems[index])` first

Comment: Yes done that already, it return nodeList : [object Object]

Comment: It is because listItems[index] object does not have "value" property in it.

Comment: Yeah verified that : 
    <input type="radio" class="versionFilter status-stable" value="/documentation/en-us/openshift_container_platform/3.11" name="versionRadio" checked="checked">

Changed querySelector to : 'input.versionFilter.status-stable'

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are creating an object with a `text` property in it. But then you try to read a property "value".

Change your for loop with that and it should be ok.

```
    for(index = 0; index < listItems.length; index++){
        console.log(listItems[index]["text"]);
    };
```

Comment: Changed :
`                    value: node.nodeValue
`
I want values only from the element, doing this undefined error is not occurring anymore but I am getting blank output.

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do, but you maybe it's not the `nodeValue` you're loking for. You should try `textContent` instead

Comment: What you can do is set a breakPoint in the map function, and look at what need from the node